# Preventing Auto-Removed invalid tags

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

Often i want to write this: Action<T>, but it comes out as Action.

1. Is there any easier way of getting it to not strip out the <T> tag (presumably because it's invalid HTML/Markup)?
2. Should they be left in?

   1. Either through a whitelist (maybe per [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)).
   2. Or because it's not valid markup.

---

Testing: [`Action<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: This is what inline code formatting is for: ``Action<T>``

Comment: How can i also make it a link?

Comment: @Jeremy, that's not quite right.

Comment: @Jeremy, but it has the extra brackets.

Comment: @George Sorry, I stupidly misunderstood what you meant. `[\`Action<T>\`][1]` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need brackets around it? Just use the backtick to indicate code, per the editing help.

[`Action<T>`](http://example.com)

```
[`Action<T>`](http://example.com)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for details.